# Restrict phase forked projects in gitlab-ci (with auto devops)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-fork

Need to restrict phases like deploy only to main project. However build and test needs to be available for all forked projects.

I have restricted the Phase: deploy to on only "master". However this restricts the build not to be executed on only feature master but also in "forked" projects master.

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - ./.m2/repository
  # keep cache across branch
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"


stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: edu-erp
    paths:
      - .m2/repository/
  script:
    - "mvn clean compile $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: edu-erp
  script:
    - "mvn test $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"

deploy_review:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy_review"
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  when:
    manual

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy_staging"
  only:
    - master

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to prod"
  only:
    - master
  when:
    manual
```

The scenario is there is an open source project on gitlab. Everyone forks the project; however the forked projects shouldn't be deploy the artefacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using the `@` syntax in the `only` key's value ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic), scroll down).

Given your group and project are called `mygroup` and `myproject` it would look like this:

```
deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to prod"
  only:
    - master@gitlab-org/gitlab-ce
  when:
    manual
```